# Eclipse for Android Maven support

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm trying to add maven support in Eclipse for Android dev.
I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7 from ADT-Bundle and I'm installing m2e plugin (Maven Integration for Eclipse) version 1.2.0.

The problem is that after plugin installation Eclipse updates to Juno v. 4.2 and I want to rollback it back to Indigo.
I've  tried to manually edit some config files (eclipse.ini, config.ini, artifacts.xml, etc.) but had no success.

Is there any way to use m2e plugin in Eclipse Indigo?
Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Eclipse 3.7 Classic (not the version from ADT-Bundle) allows to install m2e v. 1.0.200 which is compatible with Indigo and does not update Eclipse to Juno.

So this is the solution currently.